# How to format a Visualforce "snippet" to preserve line breaks of a Text Field it is programmed to mirror?

Tags: visualforce

I have a Text field on the Case object *(large or rich, doesn't matter which I use)* Let's call it **Output_Field__c**
This field needs to be displayed exactly as it shows up in my Vf "snippet". I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep the same format. Please see below for my code so far.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Case.output_field__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

When I use that code, my field does not provide breaks in paragraphs. So, if my Output_Field__c says:

```
AB - 123
CD - 456
```

The Vf snippety would say:

```
AB - 123 CD - 456
```

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: < apex:page standardController="Case" >
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Case.maybe_this_one__c}" />
< /apex:page >

Comment: `escape="false"` is not recommended as it can be abused to put dangerous (i.e. javascript) content into a page.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use this white-space (including line break) preserving [pre](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) CSS option:

```
<apex:outputText style="white-space: pre" escape="false" value="{!Case.output_field__c}" />
```

From the link:

> Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line
>   breaks. Acts like the `<pre>` tag in HTML